# Use python to extract information and data from excel file

Tags: python, scripting

I have encountered a problem on extracting the data from a database1.csv file. My database1.csv file contain a million of data and I need to extract out certain column of data which I need for it. The following figure is my coding and I found an error when running the coding. The error I got is Error: unknown dialect.

For your information:
1) I need to extract out the entire certain column which contain the information "GWM" from database1.csv file.
2) After I extracted the data and I need to put all of them into a new excel file which is result.csv file.
3) The word "GWM" is the word that I selected to extract out the certain entire column

Any recommended suggestion can be used to improve and edit my coding? Thanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea8kG.png)

Comment: let say I want to extract the entire column which contain the information that I want, so how I can do it? Thanks

Comment: You haven't told what you've tried so far. Have you tried using something like Pandas?

Comment: I have edited my question just now. Please have a look on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have Python 3 (most recent version) installed and have a command line window open in the folder your file is in.
2. Install `pandas` via `pip` or `pip3`, whichever works. (`pip install pandas`)

The code below, if saved and run in the same directory as your .xlsx file, will extract all your columns to .dat files, the filenames being the first row in said columns. From there, just choose the file you want.

```
import pandas as pd
xlsxname = input('File: ')
datacols = pd.read_excel(xlsxname, low_memory=False)
cols = list(datacols)
lencols = len(cols)
countup = 0
while countup != lencols:
    colstemp = cols[countup]
    data = pd.read_excel(xlsxname,
                       low_memory=False,
                       usecols=[colstemp])
    colsname = f'{colstemp}.dat'
    data.to_excel(colsname, index=False, header=False)
    countup = countup + 1
```

It may be ugly, it may be an idiotic and poorly-coded solution (why not just select a specific column?), but hey, it works.

(in Excel)
***...You could also left-click the number at the top of the column you want, press Ctrl-C, and paste it into a text editor, but hey...***

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to extract certain entire column from the excel file, and the excel file contain over hundred thousand of column of data, but then I just want to extract out the certain information only.